# update returning on java spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate

i changed my function to

```
    public Task assignTask(Student s) {
    Task task = null;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();
    java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime());
    String sr1 = "update Task t3 set t3.startDate = case when t3.startDate is null then '"+ date +"' else t3.startDate end, t3.student.id = ?1 where id = (SELECT t FROM Task t WHERE t.batch not in (SELECT distinct batch FROM Task t2 WHERE t2.student.id= ?2 and t2.endDate IS NOT NULL) and ((t.student.id= ?3 AND t.endDate IS NULL) OR (t.student.id IS NULL)) ORDER BY t.student.id LIMIT 1) returning t3";
    Query query1 = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(sr1).setParameter(1, s.getId()).setParameter(2, s.getId()).setParameter(3, s.getId());
    //int update = query1.executeUpdate();
    //List<Task> taskList = query1.getResultList(); // trova il task da eseguire

    if (taskList.size() > 0) {
        task = taskList.get(0);
        s.addTask(task);

    }
    return task;
}
```

from

```
    public Task assignTask(Student s) {
    Task task = null;
    String sr1 = "SELECT t FROM Task t WHERE t.batch not in (SELECT distinct batch FROM Task t2 WHERE t2.student.id= ?1 and t2.endDate IS NOT NULL) and ((t.student.id= ?2 AND t.endDate IS NULL) OR (t.student.id IS NULL)) ORDER BY t.student.id";
    Query query1 = this.entityManager.createQuery(sr1).setMaxResults(1).setParameter(1, s.getId()).setParameter(2,
            s.getId());
    List<Task> taskList = query1.getResultList(); // trova il task da eseguire

    if (taskList.size() > 0) {
        task = taskList.get(0);
        task.setStudent(s);
        if (task.getStartDate() == null) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();
            java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime());
            task.setStartDate(date);
        }

        if (task != null) {
            s.addTask(task);
            this.taskDao.save(task);
        }
    }
    return task;
}
```

the old function was working well except when 2 users ask for the task in the same time and the code assign the same task at both users
i used a `update ... returning` for the same result (if i run the sql on pgadmin it works) but on spring i don't know how execute the sql....
if i use `executeUpdate` i have a sql error `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query` and i still think i lose the return of the task (i get a `int`), if i use the `getResultList` i have an error with something like "cannot edit" or something similar

how i can use the update and return the edited line? and why i get the transactional error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about Transactions in Spring, lookup `@Trasactional`. Furthermore you should be designing your entities in a more logical way IMO. If a `Task` can only be assigned to one person, it may make more sense to have a `Student` a member of `Task`, with a `OneToOne` mapping. If you think about the `Student` class, I would ask the question is a `Student` composed of tasks, or do they have `Tasks`. If they have `Tasks` there is more likely a rule which describes what tasks they have being what has been assigned to them, as opposed to adding a field for recording tasks they have. If it is convenient to have a field, within student, then consider using a JPA query to select the tasks of a `Student`. That should be much cleaner than what you currently have.

Comment: yeah i know it could have been done better ^_^ but i got the project from other people and i'm fixing it ... the previous function was a function with 3 for and 7 nested query (with 2+ sec of exec time) i changed to the old code but if 2 student ask a new task in the same time they get the same task  ^^
i was thinking about the update returning but didn't understand how use it :)

Comment: You need to put this in an SQL restriction and use transactions, there is no other way than that to achieve consistency which is what you want.